# Show different portlet pages according to PortletPreferences

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, portal

I've a portlet that handles tariffs and tariff categories. I'm using Liferay 5.2.3 and Spring Portlet framework.

---

The portlet should work in two modes when added on page:

1. display main screen - the standard mode (MainScreenController)
2. display tariff category detail (TariffCategoryController) - when a portlet preference "showCategoryDetail" is set

I cannot figure out how to change/forward the request to TariffCategoryController when the portlet preference is set. Can you please give me a hint? Thank you!

```
@Controller("mainScreenController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MainScreenController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String handleRenderRequest() {
        return "mainScreen";
    }

    ...
}


@Controller("tariffCategoryController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class TariffCategoryController {

    @RenderMapping(params = "myaction=showTariffCategory")
    public String handleRenderRequest() {
        return "tariffCategory";
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Spring's [DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html) is not working with portlet preferences. If you need such functionality, it should be pretty easy to write your own custom [HandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/HandlerMapping.html) implementation.

But I would suggest a **different approach**. Show default view regardless any preference, If the preference is not set, show a message saying *"configuration required"* with link to **EDIT mode**. Why? Because preferences should be edited only in EDIT mode and you won't need routing based on portlet preferences.

Comment: Just noticed I've answered almost one year old question. Well hope someone will find it useful :).